# Найти площадь прямоугольника в С#

Tags: c#

В режиме диалога заданы координаты двух противоположных вершин
прямоугольника. Найти площадь прямоугольника.

```
using System;

{

    static void Main()

    {

        double x1, y1, x2, y2, P, S;
        x1 = 
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат певой точки прямоугольника: ");
        Console.Write("Введите значение x: ");
        Console.Write("Введите значение y: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат второй точки прямоугольника: ");
        Console.Write("Введите значение x: ");
        Console.Write("Введите значение y: ");
        P = 2 * Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
        Console.WriteLine("Периметр прямоугольника равен: ", P);
        S = Math.Abs(x1 - x2) * Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
        Console.WriteLine("Площадь прямоугольника равна: ", S);
    }
}
```

Comment: Абсолютную разницу между X координатами умножить на абсолютную разницу между Y координатами.

Comment: другой вариант: найти длину отрезка по координатам. это будет гипотенуза одного из двух треугольников. по теореме пифагора найти стороны... по сторонам найти площадь))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как по гипотенузе найти стороны?

Comment: Либо следует дополнительно (в условии этого нет!) предположить, что стороны параллельны осям, либо задача нерешаема.

Comment: И я как-то не наблюдаю операторов, выполняющих ввод данных.

Comment: @Grundy угол нужен еще, да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Объявляйте переменные там, где они впервые используются, если возможно.
- Локальные переменные лучше называть с маленькой буквы.
- Не жалейте букв, пишите названия словами.

Так код будет легче читать.

- Вспомните про конкатенацию и интерполяцию строк.
- Ошибка в формуле периметра, скобки потеряли.

Несмотря ни на что, формула площади у вас написана верно.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат первой точки прямоугольника: ");
Console.Write("Введите значение x: ");
double x1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Введите значение y: ");
double y1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат второй точки прямоугольника: ");
Console.Write("Введите значение x: ");
double x2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Введите значение y: ");
double y2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double width = Math.Abs(x1 - x2);
double height = Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
double perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
Console.WriteLine($"Периметр прямоугольника равен: {perimeter}");
double area = width * height;
Console.WriteLine($"Площадь прямоугольника равна: {area}");
```

Избегайте повторяющегося кода, например чтение дабла из консоли можно вынести в метод

```
static double ReadDouble(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Тогда начало кода будет выглядеть более аккуратно

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат первой точки прямоугольника: ");
double x1 = ReadDouble("Введите значение x: ");
double y1 = ReadDouble("Введите значение y: ");
Console.WriteLine("Введите значение координат второй точки прямоугольника: ");
double x2 = ReadDouble("Введите значение x: ");
double y2 = ReadDouble("Введите значение y: ");
```

В русской локализации системы десятичные дроби вводятся в консоль с разделителем дробной части "запятая". Если  введете через точку, работать не будет.

Пример вывода для 3x2

```
Введите значение координат первой точки прямоугольника:
Введите значение x: 3
Введите значение y: 3
Введите значение координат второй точки прямоугольника:
Введите значение x: 6
Введите значение y: 5
Периметр прямоугольника равен: 10
Площадь прямоугольника равна: 6
```

Comment: Спасибо))))))))

Comment: `square` - это квадрат и площадь в годроде, а площадь фигуры - `area`.